# Login process in spring mvc security doesn't work

Tags: spring-mvc, security, netbeans, authentication

I am trying to make simple login process in spring but got some error on there. Whenever login button is clicked it says '**HTTP Status 404 - Not Found**'. 
Three types of dependencies are used in this project

> **1.** spring-security-web **2.** spring-security-config **3.** spring-security-core

Spring security configuration.

**spring-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/user/dairy**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" 
        />

        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />

        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="nishan" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

I have load this configuration in web.xml in this way

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String account(ModelMap model, @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
    model.put("account", new Dairy());

    if (error != null) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "Invalid username and password!");
    }

    return "user/accounts/login-signup";
}
```

And my login form

```
<form class="form-inline" name="loginForm" method="post" action="${SITE_URL}/j_spring_security_check">
   <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" style="color:white"><strong>Username:</strong></label>
                                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pwd" style="color:white"><strong>Password:</strong></label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password"/>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></button>
                        </form>
```

And this is my project structure

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `<form-login>` as bellow:

```
<form-login 
    login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
    default-target-url="/" 
    authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
    username-parameter="username"
    password-parameter="password" 
/>
```

- `login-processing-url` Is the URL that the login form is posted to. If unspecified, it defaults to /login.
- `login-page` Is the URL for the login page. If no login URL is specified, Spring Security will automatically create a login URL 
  at GET /login and a corresponding filter to render that login URL when requested.
- `default-target-url` The URL that will be redirected to after successful authentication so you might need also change this value (depends on what you expect)

With your current configuration you should be getting Circular view redirect error and rendering or the `/login` page should be failing.

You might also need replace your `${SITE_URL}` with a context path or remove it if is your application uses the root one (listing e.g. on http://localhots:8080/)

Comment: After adding the line `login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check` **404- Page not found** error is solved but when i enter a correct username is shows an error and error is like this **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"** but work fine on inputting incorrect username and password

Comment: Which version of Spring security and Spring do you use? For me it works fine.

Comment: Earlier i was using spring-security of version 5 and i replace it to the 4 and it works on me. Thanks @Peter Jurkovic for your suggestion